# Option for Select All not triggering in Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I can't get my 'Select All' option to trigger when I select it. But if after selecting it I then select another option, then all options do indeed become selected.  I'm obviously trying to get everything selected on the first click.  Spent all day on this going through the posts and moving the 'select all' part of my code around.  I'm sure I keep missing something stupid.  Appreciate any help at all.  Relevant code is at the end of the JS (see fiddle).

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>


  <div class="CountryDropContainer">
  <select id="CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn" name="CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn" class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple="multiple">

<option value="ChooseAll">SELECT ALL</option>  
<option class="myEuropeCountries" value="UN40a" title="Austria" >Austria</option>
<option class="myOceaniaCountries" value="UN36a" title="New Zealand" >New Zealand</option>
<option class="myOceaniaCountries" value="UN554a" title="Australia" >Australia</option>
<option class="myOceaniaCountries" value="UN936a" title="Other Oceania" >Other Oceania</option>

</select>
</div>
```

.

```
    $(function() {

  var S2MultiCheckboxes = function(options, element) {
    var self = this;
    self.options = options;
    self.$element = $(element);
    var values = self.$element.val();
    self.$element.removeAttr('multiple');
    self.select2 = self.$element.select2({

      allowClear: true, // Puts little 'X' in top placeholder  
      //minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
      placeholder: options.placeholder,
      closeOnSelect: false,

      templateSelection: function() {
        return self.options.templateSelection(self.$element.val() || [], $('option', self.$element).length);
      },
      templateResult: function(result) {
        if (result.loading !== undefined)
          return result.text;
        return $('<div>').text(result.text).addClass(self.options.wrapClass);
      }
    }).data('select2');
    self.select2.$results.off("mouseup").on("mouseup", ".select2-results__option[aria-selected]", (function(self) {
      return function(evt) {
        var $this = $(this);

        var data = $this.data('data');

        if ($this.attr('aria-selected') === 'true') {
          self.trigger('unselect', {
            originalEvent: evt,
            data: data
          });
          return;
        }

        self.trigger('select', {
          originalEvent: evt,
          data: data
        });
      }
    })(self.select2));
    self.$element.attr('multiple', 'multiple').val(values).trigger('change.select2');
  }


  $.fn.extend({
    select2MultiCheckboxes: function() {
      var options = $.extend({
        wrapClass: 'wrap'
      }, arguments[0]);

      this.each(function() {
        new S2MultiCheckboxes(options, this);
      });
    }
  });

});



$(function() {

  $('#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn').select2MultiCheckboxes({
    closeOnSelect: false,
    width: "auto",
    placeholder: '',
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
      return markup;
    },

    templateSelection: function(selected, total) {
      return ("Select Country - " + ' ' + "") + selected.length + (" of ") + total + ("\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0");
    }

  })


  // --------------------------

  // Select ALL

  $('#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn').on('select2:select', function(e) {
    var data = e.params.data;

    if (e.params.data.text == 'SELECT ALL') {
      $("#CountryBoxesContainerID_prodn option").prop("selected", true);
    }

  });


});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtyhzm3b/

Comment: you have found any solution about this

Comment: No I didn't.  I had to give up and use a solution other than Select2.  Do you know of a solution?

Comment: not yet but, I can try to find out the solutions